# C# TcpClient не полностью записывает UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, websocket, кодировка

```
        byte[] WriteBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Str);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WriteBuffer));

        client.GetStream().Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
```

вот такой код. Проверенно, что WriteBuffer декодируется нормально, но в браузер передается строка, на ~10-20 символов меньше, чем в строке. Раньше кодировка была ASCII, и все работало хорошо. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: С Английским текстом таких проблем нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD2: Скриншот консоли вывода Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WriteBuffer));[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй вызвать Flush() для стрима после записи

Comment: @Umed, не помогло =(

Comment: Str это точно строка в UTF?

Comment: Content-Length правильно считается по размеру отправляемых данных, а не по размеру строки?

Comment: @vitidev, возможно, тут и есть ошибка, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо, вы были правы. Исправил, теперь все работает

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно заметил vitidev, ошибка была в том, что `Content-Length` подсчитывался от длины строки, а не от размера данных

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что вы [забыли `using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

```
using (var ns = client.GetStream())
{
    ns.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, что нет, так тоже не помогает. Заметил, что с английским текстом все отображается нормально

Comment: @Артем: А если строка такая: `"english text 1 русский текст english text 2"`?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
        english text 1 русский текст english text 2
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>english text 1 русский текст english text 2</h1>
    <p>english text 1 русский текст en

Comment: если писать без "русский текст", то разметка нормальная

Comment: @Артем: Окей, а какую кодировку вы отдаёте в http-ответе?

Comment: это и есть передача http ответа

Comment: @Артем: Ну, у вас же должно где-то передаваться `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`? Покажите, что у вас в строке `Str`.

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: @Артем: А если добавить `; charset=utf-8` всё же?

Comment: vitidev правильно ответил на вопрос. Проблема была в неправильном подсчете Content-Length